# How to check if I have a closed circle-like object in the image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am analyzing some images, where I am zooming on image and to detect a such objects ( animals on the field with a thermal camera ):
[image]

And after the OTSU method, I end up with such an image:
[image]

I would like to know how I can check if the black-and-white image is a circle-like image; as you can see, if not, I can say an animal does not exist on that part of the image.

Comment: Why not just threshold and get the contour if you want a closed ring?

Comment: how is this "circle-like"? Anyways if you want to check for closed "objects" you will either have to use a morphological "closing" operator (with the risk to also close non-objects) or use a better contour extraction or segmentation technique.

Comment: Fit ellipse and then some evaluation...?